# Area between the graph of each function and the x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Determine the area between $x$-axis and the graph of the following functions:
>
> (1) $ i(x) = x^3-3x^2+2x \text{ on } [-1,3] $
>
> (2) $ (x^2-1)(x^2-4) = 0 \text{ on } [-3,4] $

My solutions:

(1) $ x_1 = 0 \;x_2 = 1\; x_3 = 2 $

$$ \int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3-x^2 ∣_{-1}^0 + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3-x^2 ∣_{0}^{1} + \int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3-x^2 ∣_{1}^{2} + \int_{2}^3 \frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3-x^2 ∣_{2}^{3}$$

$$ ( 0 - \frac{9}{4}) + (\frac{1}{4}) + (0 - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{-63}{4}+8) = -10 $$

The correct answer is 5 What's wrong with my solution ?

(2) $x_1 = -2 \;x_2 = -1\; x_3 = 1\; x_4 = 2 $

$$ \int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3+4x ∣_{-3}^{-2} + \int_{-2}^{-1} \frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3+4x ∣_{-2}^{-1} + \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3+4x ∣_{-1}^{1} + \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3+4x ∣_{1}^{2} + \int_{2}^{4} \frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3+4x ∣_{2}^{4} $$

$$ \left[\left(\frac{-32}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{-168}{5}\right)\right] + \left[\left(\frac{-16}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{-32}{5}\right)\right]+\left[\left(\frac{16}{5}\right)-\left(-\frac{-16}{5}\right)\right] + \left[\left(\frac{32}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{16}{5}\right)\right]+ \left[\left(\frac{784}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{32}{5}\right)\right]$$

$$  = \frac{952}{5} $$

The answer in the book is $\frac{578}{5}$ , so what's wrong ?

Comment: You divided $(1)$ in four parts, but notice how some of the integrals yield negative values.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you're finding the *net signed area* between the curves and the $x$-axis. To find the area between a curve $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis on an interval $[a,b],$ you must find $$\int_a^b|f(x)|\,dx,$$ instead. (Also, you've made calculation errors in both attempts.)

For example, note that $x^3-3x^2+2x\ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ and $[2,3],$ while $x^3-3x^2+2x\le 0$ on $[-1,0]$ and $[1,2].$ Hence, using the notation $$I(a,b)=\int_a^b(x^3-3x^2+2x)\,dx$$ for brevity, we have $$\int_{-1}^3|x^3-3x^2+2x|\,dx = -I(-1,0)+I(0,1)-I(1,2)+I(2,3).$$ At that point, we proceed mostly as you did, but keeping those signs in mind. $\frac14x^4-x^3+x^2$ is an antiderivative of $x^3-3x^2+2x,$ so by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have in general that $$I(a,b)=\left[\frac14x^4-x^3+x^2\right]_a^b.$$ In particular, $$I(-1,0)=0-\frac94=-\frac94\\I(0,1)=\frac14-0=\frac14\\I(1,2)=0-\frac14=-\frac14\\I(2,3)=\frac94-0=\frac94,$$ and so $$\int_{-1}^3\left|x^3-3x^2+2x\right|\,dx=-\left(-\frac94\right)+\frac14-\left(-\frac14\right)+\frac94=5.$$

Comment: Thank you :) But what about the second one ?

Comment: For the second one, you'll take the same sort of approach. Split $\int_{-3}^4\left|x^4-5x^2+4\right|\,dx$ up into five integrals (as you did, but with the wrong integrand), determine on which of those intervals the function $x^4-5x^2+4$ is positive and on which it is negative (so we know whether we need to add or subtract), then use FTC to find all five integrals, and finally combine them together (adding and subtracting as appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Also you're a little unclear on the integration process.  You have the integral sign, something that resembles the integrated expression (neither is correct), and the evaluation limits of integration all rolled into one expression on the left-hand side.

Here's how one of the terms in each should go down:

$ \int_{-1}^{0} (x^3-3x^2+2x) dx = (\frac{1}{4}x^4-x^3+x^2)|_{-1}^{0} = 0 - \frac{1}{4}$.

and

$ \int_{-3}^{-2} (x^2-1)(x^2-4) dx = \int (x^4 - 5x^2 + 4) dx = (\frac{1}{5}x^5 - \frac{5}{3}x^3 + 4x)|_{-3}^{-2}$.